# I have a graph in my code but it does not display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

```js
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        //define chart clolors ( you maybe add more colors if you want or flot will add it automatic )
        var chartColours = ['#96CA59', '#3F97EB', '#72c380', '#6f7a8a', '#f7cb38', '#5a8022', '#2c7282'];

        //generate random number for charts
        randNum = function() {
          return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + 40 - 20))) + 20;
        };

        var d1 = [];
        //var d2 = [];

        //here we generate data for chart
        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
          d1.push([new Date(Date.today().add(i).days()).getTime(), randNum() + i + i + 10]);
          //    d2.push([new Date(Date.today().add(i).days()).getTime(), randNum()]);
        }

        var chartMinDate = d1[0][0]; //first day
        var chartMaxDate = d1[20][0]; //last day

        var tickSize = [1, "day"];
        var tformat = "%d/%m/%y";

        //graph options
        var options = {
          grid: {
            show: true,
            aboveData: true,
            color: "#3f3f3f",
            labelMargin: 10,
            axisMargin: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            borderColor: null,
            minBorderMargin: 5,
            clickable: true,
            hoverable: true,
            autoHighlight: true,
            mouseActiveRadius: 100
          },
          series: {
            lines: {
              show: true,
              fill: true,
              lineWidth: 2,
              steps: false
            },
            points: {
              show: true,
              radius: 4.5,
              symbol: "circle",
              lineWidth: 3.0
            }
          },
          legend: {
            position: "ne",
            margin: [0, -25],
            noColumns: 0,
            labelBoxBorderColor: null,
            labelFormatter: function(label, series) {
              // just add some space to labes
              return label + '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            },
            width: 40,
            height: 1
          },
          colors: chartColours,
          shadowSize: 0,
          tooltip: true, //activate tooltip
          tooltipOpts: {
            content: "%s: %y.0",
            xDateFormat: "%d/%m",
            shifts: {
              x: -30,
              y: -50
            },
            defaultTheme: false
          },
          yaxis: {
            min: 0
          },
          xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            minTickSize: tickSize,
            timeformat: tformat,
            min: chartMinDate,
            max: chartMaxDate
          }
        };
        var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder33x"), [{
          label: "Email Sent",
          data: d1,
          lines: {
            fillColor: "rgba(150, 202, 89, 0.12)"
          }, //#96CA59 rgba(150, 202, 89, 0.42)
          points: {
            fillColor: "#fff"
          }
        }], options);
      });
    </script>
```

```html
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Periodic Analysis</h2>
                    <div class="filter">
                      <div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        <span>December 30, 2014 - January 28, 2015</span> <b class="caret"></b>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x_content">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                      <div class="demo-container" style="height:280px">
                        <div id="placeholder33x" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
                      </div>
                     
</div> 
        </div> 
  </div>
                 </div>
```

This is the source code of aspx page.There is  a graph in the code.As far as i know chart.js and float.js files and jquery.min.js  files are enough to render the graph output.I have referenced chart.js and flot.js and jquery files,have written the necessary scripts,still the graph would not show up.please help.

Comment: Do you have messages in the browser console ? Which line in your code is supposed to create the chart itself ? jQuery is properly included in your page ?

Comment: NO there are no messages in the browser.Its blank.ya jquery,flot,chart.js files are included,still it would not show  up